# Pyspark merge 2 dataframes without losing data

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm looking for joining 2 pyspark dataframes without losing any data inside. Easiest way would be showing you with example. Might even count them together and sort. If null in the `desktop` or `phone` column, then it should equal 0 in the output.

I tried:

```
desktop_df.join(phone_df, on='query')\
          .fillna(0).orderBy("desktop", ascending=False)\
          .show(20)
```

*(doesn't have the total column yet, so I'm ordering it by count1)*

But this approach doesn't seems to be working - doesn't show zeros at all.

**desktop_df**:

```
query  |desktop|
----------------
query1 |  12   | 
----------------
query2 |  23   |
----------------
query3 |  8    |
----------------
query4 |  11   |
----------------
query6 |  45   |
----------------
query9 |  89   |
```

**phone_df**:

```
query  | phone |
----------------
query1 |  21   | 
----------------
query2 |  33   |
----------------
query4 |  11   |
----------------
query5 |  55   |
----------------
query6 |  45   |
----------------
query7 | 1234  |
----------------
query8 | 4321  |
----------------
query10|  10   |
----------------
query11|  1    |
```

**Output I'm looking for**:

```
query  | desktop| phone  | total |
--------------------------------
query8 |   0    |  4321  | 4321  |
--------------------------------
query7 |   0    |  1234  | 1234  |
--------------------------------
query6 |   45   |   45   |  90   |
--------------------------------
query9 |   89   |   0    |  89   |
--------------------------------
query2 |   23   |   33   |  56   |
--------------------------------
query5 |   0    |   55   |  55   |
--------------------------------
query1 |   12   |   21   |  33   |
--------------------------------
query4 |   11   |   11   |  22   |
--------------------------------
query10|   0    |   10   |  10   |
--------------------------------
query3 |   8    |   0    |  8    |
--------------------------------
query11|   0    |   1    |  1    |
```

## Wanted solutions

```
df = desktop_df.join(phone_df, on=["query"], how='fullouter').fillna(0).withColumn("total",col("desktop")+col("phone")).show(200)
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import max

desktop_df = df.filter("hwType == 'DESKTOP'").groupby("query").count().orderBy("count", ascending=False).withColumnRenamed('count','desktop')
phone_df = df.filter("hwType == 'PHONE'").groupby("query").count().orderBy("count", ascending=False).withColumnRenamed('count','phone')

# add missing column to each dataframe
desktop_df = desktop_df.withColumn('phone', lit(0)).select('query', 'desktop', 'phone')
phone_df = phone_df.withColumn('desktop', lit(0)).select('query', 'desktop', 'phone')

# union all and agg to select max value
phone_df.unionAll(desktop_df).groupBy('query').agg(max(col('desktop')).alias('desktop'), max(col('phone')).alias('phone'))
# withColumn('total', col('desktop') + col('phone')) \
#    .orderBy(col('total').desc()) \
#    .show()
```

Comment: use a full outer join, then fillna: `desktop_df.join(phone_df, on=["query"], how='fullouter').fillna(0)`

Comment: looks like 
`df = desktop_df.join(phone_df, on=["query"], how='fullouter').fillna(0).withColumn("total",col("desktop")+col("phone")).show(200)` is my perfect solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `unionAll` and then `groupBy`.

Example:

```
desktop_data = [("query1", 12), ("query2", 23), ("query3", 8),
                ("query4", 11), ("query6", 45), ("query9", 89)]

phone_data = [("query1", 21), ("query2", 33), ("query4", 11), ("query5", 55), ("query6", 45),
             ("query7", 1234), ("query8", 4321), ("query10", 10), ("query11", 1)]

desktop_df = spark.createDataFrame(desktop_data, ['query', 'count1'])
phone_df = spark.createDataFrame(phone_data, ['query', 'count2'])

# add missing column to each dataframe
desktop_df = desktop_df.withColumn('count2', lit(0)).select('query', 'count1', 'count2')
phone_df = phone_df.withColumn('count1', lit(0)).select('query', 'count1', 'count2')

# union all and agg to select max value
phone_df.unionAll(desktop_df) \
   .groupBy('query').agg(max(col('count1')).alias('count1'), max(col('count2')).alias('count2')) \
   .withColumn('total', col('count1') + col('count2')) \
   .orderBy(col('total').desc()) \
   .show()

+-------+------+------+-----+
|  query|count1|count2|total|
+-------+------+------+-----+
| query8|     0|  4321| 4321|
| query7|     0|  1234| 1234|
| query6|    45|    45|   90|
| query9|    89|     0|   89|
| query2|    23|    33|   56|
| query5|     0|    55|   55|
| query1|    12|    21|   33|
| query4|    11|    11|   22|
|query10|     0|    10|   10|
| query3|     8|     0|    8|
|query11|     0|     1|    1|
+-------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Just adjusted your solution to mine a little and I'm getting an error about Column is not iterable. Most likely in the max(col("count1")) line. I'll add the adjusted solution.

Comment: The example wortks fine. So you're probably missing something on what you added. Can you add the complete error message you get?

Comment: @Leemosh You have to import `from pyspark.sql.functions import max`. It's conflicting with Python `max` function.

Comment: You were right. This solution works perfectly as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

May be try inner join on query column. And find "Total" by adding column values.

```
df = desktop_df.join(phone_df, desktop_df.query==phone_df.query,"full").select(desktop_df.query,"count1","count2").fillna(0).withColumn("total",col("count1")+col("count2"))
```

Comment: Try adding `python` and `pandas` to the post tags and specify your problem better.

Comment: Let's say I have 2 dataframes. First is with query + count of searches over the desktop. Second is with query + count of searches over the phone. And I'm trying to connect them in some way. (The way I showed higher) Problem is that I need every record. Example: query is "asdfasdfasdf" which was searched once over the phone and 0 times over the desktop. So I need the record to be as ' asdfasdfasdf |0 |1 |1 ' - query|desktop|phone|total. Not interested in pandas tho, my dataset is too big for pandas.

Comment: I'll try this solution as soon as possible. Thanks for reply! :)

Comment: Hi! Tried the solution - problem is that I'm getting `null` in the query column whenever there is a 0 in the desktop column.

Almost perfect!

Comment: @Leemosh change `desktop_df.query` to `coalesce(desktop_df.query, phone_df.query)`  in the select to get ride of the nulls.

Comment: @ blackbishop Didn't really get rid of the nulls with this, but your solution is great and mix of solutions by @abhaykagalkar and jxc works fine as well too.